# SQL to Linq conversion with cross join

Tags: sql, linq, join, cross-join

Can someone please help in converting the following sql to linq in c#?

```
select s.SYSTEM_NAME,
       r.RESET_CODE,
       COUNT(v.reset_code) 
  from (select distinct system_name 
          from tbl) s 
cross join (select distinct reset_code 
              from tbl) r 
left join tbl v on v.SYSTEM_NAME = s.SYSTEM_NAME 
               and v.RESET_CODE=r.RESET_CODE 
 group by s.SYSTEM_NAME,r.RESET_CODE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross joins are generally represented as multiple from clauses in a query expression, or a call to SelectMany in extension method syntax.

So the first part of your query might be:

```
var query = from systemName in db.Table.Select(x => x.SystemName).Distinct()
            from resetCode in db.Table.Select(x => x.ResetCode).Distinct()
            ...
```

Left outer joins are usually represented with a "join ... into ..." query, possibly like this:

```
var query = from systemName in db.Table.Select(x => x.SystemName).Distinct()
            from resetCode in db.Table.Select(x => x.ResetCode).Distinct()
            join tmp in db.Table on 
                new { ResetCode = resetCode, SystemName = systemName } 
                equals new { tmp.ResetCode, tmp.SystemName }
                into tmpGroup
            select new { ResetCode = resetCode,
                         SystemName = systemName,
                         Count = tmpGroup.Count() };
```

I'm not sure about the Count part, to be honest... I'm not 100% sure what the `COUNT(v.ResetCode)` does in your original SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved my problem. I added the column name in the count() to have 0 for missing resetcodes. the linq query shows me the results correctly. But will niot having group by have an impact?? just curious to know what role it actually plays..

Comment: @Sasi: You're performing a "group by" operation with the "join ... into" operation, effectively. It uses the GroupJoin LINQ query operator.